# node cmd getting hangs while doing 'npm install' at fsevents point

Tags: node.js, angular, npm

i am trying to install anugalr2 through npm command "npm install". but when it reaches some point that is in fsevents. the command prompt getting stuck. nothing is happening after that. PFb the cmd image
[image]

any suggestions /advice will be helpful

Update :

when i try with `npm i --no-optional`. it is getting stuck at ""core-js" package

```
D:\Angular2\quickstart-master>npm i --no-optional
npm WARN deprecated minimatch@0.3.0: Please update to minimatch 3.0.2 or highe
to avoid a RegExp DoS issue
npm WARN deprecated express@2.5.11: express 2.x series is deprecated
npm WARN deprecated connect@1.9.2: connect 1.x series is deprecated
[            ......] - extract:core-js: sill pacote core-js@https://registry.n
```

Comment: try to run `npm i --no-optional`
This will skip installation of optional dependencies. As far as I remember `fsevents` only for macos

Answer (score 14):

after i cleaned npm cache it worked for me

`npm cache clean --force`

Comment: This did not work for me

Answer (score 5):

As @RidgeA said in their comment...

Use `npm i --no-optional`. This will not install optional dependencies, one of which is `fsevents`. The reason it is getting stuck is because `fsevents` is written for Mac (see https://www.npmjs.com/package/fsevents).

Comment: when i try with this i am getting below error . i have updated the post also

Comment: D:\Angular2\quickstart-master>npm i --no-optional
npm WARN deprecated minimatch@0.3.0: Please update to minimatch 3.0.2 or highe
to avoid a RegExp DoS issue
npm WARN deprecated express@2.5.11: express 2.x series is deprecated
npm WARN deprecated connect@1.9.2: connect 1.x series is deprecated
[            ......] - extract:core-js: sill pacote core-js@https://registry.n

Comment: What happens if you do `npm i minimatch` then `npm i express` then `npm i connect`

Comment: that is not the issue. the issue is that I am not able to complete this installation process. it hangs on fsevents

Comment: Booligoosh i am able to install it one by one

Answer (score 0):

I can see your path is not that long but in my case a problem was with a too long path.

So the solution was to move project to a location with shorter path, like: `D:\my-project\`

Answer (score 0):

I managed to install without problems after moving the project to a folder with a shorter path. C:\Themes

Answer (score 0):

After updating npm version I forgot about this problem.

Answer (score 0):

npm won't work if you try to install on USB devices, try changing the directory to your hard drive.